# head.appendChild(script) JSONP fails in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsonp, appendchild

Im working with JSONP calls for Cross Site interaction.

The Front End code is as simple as:

```
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; 
var s    = document.createElement('script');
s.src    = "https://example.com/meta?p1=a&p2=b&...&pn=n&callback=myFunc";
s.type   = 'text/javascript';

head.appendChild(s);
```

This works on 4 of the 5BB (5 Big Browsers: Chrome, FF, IE, Opera, Safari in their current stable versions) but it doesn't work in Google Chrome.

Whenever I try to run this I get in the console:

> *GET https://example.com/meta?p1=a&p2=b&...&pn=n&callback=myFunc  miscript.js:line 20*
>
> *myFunc                                                           miscript.js:line 20*

Where line 20 refers to

```
head.appendChild(s)
```

I tried using jQuery to create and append the script and the error still remains only in Chrome, the rest of the 5BB keep working.

The GET inmediately fails.
In Chromes debugger "Network" tab I see

> url    = https://example.com/meta?p1=a&p2=b&...&pn=n&callback=myFunc
>
> method = GET
>
> status = (failed)
>
> type   = pending ...

UPDATE1:

This failure presents whenever I try to run this from Argentina. From USA all works okey in Chrome. (Weird Ja?)

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. `appendChild` works, but the request  to the JSONP resource fails. Why does the request fail?

Comment: Are you running this on a server or locally ?

Comment: please post a fiddle.....

Comment: Im running it in both locally and a server, and in both it behaves exactly the same. It also only fails from my current location, Argentina, but from USA it works.